# In the first half of 20th century, how was gold inspected for authenticity?

Tags: 20th-century, economy, science, industrial-history, gold

Let's say this for the years 1900 - 1950, before we had modern analysis tools. When trade payments were made in gold, how was the gold inspected for quality? How did they assess the purity of gold, such that they knew a particular ingot weighed 3 kg but was only 0.9 pure and thus they were really getting 2.7 kg of actual gold?

I'm imagining this for trade agreements. At the port, someone exchanges gold for the goods. Surely that gold was inspected somehow.

Comment: Wasn't gold primarily traded through securities already by then, with physical delivery of gold the exception rather than the rule?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Primarily by whom? I'm sure there were many parts of the world at this time, not necessarily the West, that did a lot of trade with physical gold and silver. If you just look at WW1 and WW2 and all the other wars of the first half of the 20th century, I think it's pretty likely that cash and carry was required to show up at the port or they wouldn't let you take the goods.

Comment: Seems doubtful to me to be honest. The reason international trade collapsed so fast during the 1929 crisis had less to do with a rise in protectionism than in had to do with the fact that letters of credit were used all over the place. The general mistrust of banks led sellers of goods and their banks to not trust that these securities would be worth the paper they were printed on. Much like in 2007-2009, banks were no longer trusting each other. Hardly anybody was traveling around with ingots at the time.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Ah, so you mean, after the Great Depression, people were more likely to exchange gold because they didn't trust the banks and their credits anymore? That's fine. I'll edit the OP to cover 1900 - 1950 instead of averaging it at 1925, 4 years before the Great Depression.

Comment: Yes, the one where FDR issued [executive order 6102](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Order_6102) "forbidding the Hoarding of gold coin, gold bullion, and gold certificates within the continental United States" and where just about every country went off the gold standard.

Comment: I think you're forgetting Archimedes :-)  A gold object is going to have a certain density, which will be less if it's alloyed with other metals.  So if you weigh & measure a coin or gold bar, you can see whether the weight varies from its expected value.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy That is one of the most ridiculous things I've ever heard. Why would the govt. confiscate all "gold hoarding" unless **gold was all the more valuable?** Times of crisis, be it from war or economic crash, always see the value of gold increase. Going off the gold standard just lets a govt. print and float its own money, e.g., inflation, to pay its own things **without having to resort to a much more limited stock of gold.**

Comment: Also, unless you're going to claim that **literally no gold** trading went on at any port on Earth during this time, let's please stop getting sidetracked. My question is about how gold was verified on the spot, not about how common or uncommon this was.

Comment: @DrZ214: it's not ridiculous, it happened. And yes, my point precisely is that no physical gold was getting shipped around on any regular basis back then, thus making the premise behind the question entirely moot.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Please provide a source that `no physical gold was getting shipped around on any regular basis`.

Comment: @DrZ214: I did further up - letters of credit were used. To avoid traveling with gold in your cargo hold where it might get stolen by pirates, you'd carry letters of credit instead. Banks would then hold claims against each other, and seldom take actual delivery. When 1929 occurred the entire thing went to hell because banks no longer trusted each other when it came to credit worthiness. Letters of credit were used [as far back as 3000BC](http://infodagang2u.blogspot.hu/2007/11/history-of-letter-of-credit.html). You might want to peek into Debt: The First 5,000 Years by David Graeber for more.

Comment: Just an observation, but gold bullion certainly _was_ being transported on a fairly regular basis in the early 20th century. An example I happen to know about is the Japanese steamer [Futami Maru](http://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/23843258). She went down of the Australian coast in August 1900. A consignment of gold bullion that she was transporting [was salvaged](http://www.self.gutenberg.org/articles/List_of_shipwrecks_in_1900#August) at the time.

Comment: In India there was a type of stone called Kosthi Pathar, if you rub this stone with any other pseudo golden coloured metal, it will come out.

Comment: @jamesqf Couldn't you just include offsetting amounts of heavier and lighter cheaper materials to manage the same density value?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest: The problem is that there aren't many materials that are both heavier than gold, and cheaper.  Only things that come to mind are tungsten, which is difficult to work due to its high melting point, and uranium, which was probably not common pre-WWII.  A bit of Googling found this article on creating realistic fake gold bars: http://www.popsci.com/diy/article/2008-03/how-make-convincing-fake-gold-bars

Comment: here is a relevant link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71629/is-there-a-tungsten-alloy-more-dense-than-gold

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As Denis observed in the comments above, for many countries, gold would have been traded through securities in the first half of the twentieth century. In those cases the physical transfer of the gold would indeed have been the exception, rather than the rule. That said, there would undoubtedly have been a great many cases where gold was transferred as payment, and some form of [metallurgical assay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallurgical_assay) to ensure its purity would have been required.

Apart from a few modern techniques like [X-ray fluorescence](http://www.the-experts.com/x-ray-fluorescence-xrf-explained) (XRF), most of the techniques used to assay gold were in use long before the twentieth century. (In any event, XRF - although non-detructive - can be fooled by surface treatments like gold-plating). The most likely techniques, however, would be using a "[touchstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchstone_(assaying_tool))" or conducting a "Fire Assay".

In the example you give, where the gold was to be exchanged for the goods at the port, testing would probably have been carried out with a touchstone. The use of touchstones dates back to antiquity, and they [remain in use to this day](https://www.mgsrefining.com/blog/2011/08/25/Types-of-Assay-How-Precious-Metals-are-Tested-for-Purity). These could easily distinguish between, for example, 14 carat and 24 carat gold (I've done it myself), and I read that [experienced testers](https://www.ganoksin.com/article/testing-precious-metals-and-alloys/) can achieve accuracies of better than 5%.

If a more accurate assessment was required, a [Fire Assay](http://www.midwestrefineries.com/refiningandassaying.htm) may have been carried out on a sample from one or more of the ingots. This technique is destructive, but has been available since the sixteenth century (a version is mentioned in Agricola's [De Re Metallica](https://archive.org/details/deremetallica50agri)). I would very much doubt that a Fire Assay could have been carried out at the port though (unless specialist facilities were available there expressly for that purpose).

[One of the reasons that national mints introduced mint-marks on bullion [from about the eighteenth century](http://www.coinandbullionpages.com/gold-bullion-bars/history-of-gold-bars.html) was to assure its quality and so eliminate the need for such testing].

Today, a fire assay on gold can achieve an [accuracy of better than 0.05%](http://www.lbma.org.uk/assets/17_Cassagne.pdf). My reading of the text of [A Manual of Assaying](https://archive.org/details/amanualassaying00millgoog), by Arthur Stanley Miller, seems to suggest that similar accuracies would have been achievable when it was published in 1905.

Comment: Thanks, the touchstone thing seems quick and easy, but I wonder if it can assay the **exact purity** of the gold instead of just distinguishing between 14c and 24c? I have this impression from hollywood of some guy looking thru a monocule or microscope at the gold, but I'm not sure how accurate this would be back then. I look forward to whatever else you can find later.

Comment: To clarify: A fire assay is "destructive", in that it, usually, destroys what's being assayed as anything other than a hunk of precious metal. It does not actually destroy the gold. For instance, if you are having an item of jewelry fire assayed it won't be usable as jewelry, but will still be a valuable piece of precious metal. In a fire assay, normally only a representative sample of the material is actually assayed, but obtaining a sample that is actually representative may require melting the entire amount and mixing. The assayed gold is recovered as part of the normal fire assay process.

Comment: This is a pretty darn detailed answer, thanks! It looks like the touchstone can only verify gold quality on the outside, and can't tell if it might have a core of lead. Weighing and measuring could, so I'm going to research the periodic table of elements for density near gold (lead is off by a factor of 2), and maybe give a supplementary comment if I find anything.

Comment: @DrZ214 - "I'm going to research the periodic table of elements for density near gold (lead is off by a factor of 2)"  One of the primary benefits of using gold as an exchange medium is that there are no heavier elements that aren't actually even more expensive.  The only elements you could use that wouldn't be detected by weight are basically tungsten, platinum, iridium, and a wide variety of radioactive elements (which can clearly be detected by other means anyway).  All of these are more valuable than gold is, as well as being denser.

Comment: @Jules Tungsten is more valuable than gold? Are you talking in 1925 like my OP, or modern times?

Comment: @Jules Seems to me, if the gold you're using as an exchange medium isn't *pure* gold, then a crook doesn't need something heavier than gold, just something heavier than whatever the gold is supposed to be alloyed with.

Comment: @bof understanding that this is an old question and an old comment, heavier doesn't really equate to density. If the alloy isn't denser then there would need to be more of it to match the expected weight, right? (IANAP)

Comment: @CGCampbell: Tungsten and uranium are *nearly* as dense as gold. Osmium and iridium are even *more* dense. (I assume that "heavier" was used here in the simplification of the term density.)

Comment: @DevSolar And Tungsten, Uranium, Osmium or Iridium were commonly used with gold in the first half of the 20th century?

Comment: @CGCampbell: Whether any of those was ever used to counterfeit gold wasn't my point, I was just pointing out the physical characteristics.

Answer (score 3):

For smaller transactions, early 20th century literature has a lot of references of people biting into the gold. See more detail in [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/18108/27319) to a [closely related question in the history section of Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8810/27319).

Answer (score 3):

A classical test that does not seem to have yet been mentioned was a literal "acid test": the purported golden item is rubbed onto a stone, after which the mark is treated first with *aqua fortis* (nitric acid). True gold should not dissolve in it; a follow-up treatment with *[aqua regia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqua_regia)* should then dissolve the mark made, if the golden article is genuine. (See e.g. [this](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=Jng6AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA128).)

Comment: This sounds a lot like the Touchstone test kit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchstone_(assaying_tool)